# Looking for a better explanation on $\cap$ and joint probabilities?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a few things I am hoping to get clarified.  Let's say we want to determine $Pr(A \cap B)$.

- Can we say $Pr(A \cap B)$ is the joint probability of A and B occurring?  Or is that the wrong term to use?  In calculating conditional probabilities, this seems like it's the correct term to use to describe the numerator.  Assuming A and B are independent, we have $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) * Pr(B)$.  If dependent, we have $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A | B) * Pr(B)$
- However, we also have the formula $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cup B)$.  In this case, would you still describe $Pr(A \cap B)$ as a joint probability?

If you were explaining the above concept to someone completely new at statistics, how would you explain the situation where we have two formulas for $Pr(A \cap B)$?  To be more specific, how would you explain to someone when to use which formula and why there are two formulas?  I am hoping to be very precise in the way I explain to others.

Comment: So one thing I am trying to explain is the definition of an event.  The specific outcome of rolling a die and flipping a coin is a joint probability - you wouldn't call the outcome of a die and coin flip separate events - as the event itself is the specific combination of the coin flip and die roll.  Nor would you call it separate trials - as we only have a single trial here.  Is there another word to use here?

Comment: Both formulae are correct in giving the joint probability, though one may be more useful than the other in particular circumstances.  Your question seems like asking why you have both $6=2 \times 3$ and $6=5+1$